# Do PL/pgSQL functions autocommit on their own?

Tags: postgresql, function, transactions, plpgsql, commit

I have a PL/pgSQL function as follows on PostgreSQL 11:

```sql
create or replace function public.process_single_usage(usage_p "UsagePs")
  returns text
  language plpgsql
as $function$
declare
return_msg text;
   -- Variables used for business logic
begin
   -- Business logic and error handling, return_msg variable is assigned to an error message on failure 
   -- or to an empty string on success.

   -- A bunch of insert statements if no error arises.
   return return_msg;
end
$function$;
```

Could I use a second function to run the first one on every row of the table and rollback every insert if any one row results with an error message or should I need to use a single function controlling the transaction?

Comment: The function is always part of the transaction of the _caller_.  And you can't use commit or rollback in a function

Comment: So then, since one functions is calling, would that mean there a two transactions on a given time, one nested the other one?

Comment: No, everything runs in a single transaction which is defined by the caller of the first function

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: While that's true, I don't think it stands in the way of what the OP is trying to achieve. I added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Could I use a second function to run the first one on every row of the table and rollback every insert if any one row results with an error message

A [`FUNCTION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) always runs in a single transaction. But I don't think that stands in the way of what you are trying to do. A [block](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html) with an `EXCEPTION` clause can trap exceptions and roll back subtransactions. Depending on what "every insert" is supposed to mean exactly, that might work for you.

If "every row" means *every row in the whole operation (multiple calls of the child function)*, then you don't need to do anything extra. It's default behavior to roll back *everything* if an exception occurs.

If "every row" means *every row affected by a single call of the child function*, then consider [the manual on *Trapping Errors*:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING)

> When an error is caught by an `EXCEPTION` clause, the local variables
> of the PL/pgSQL function remain as they were when the error occurred,
> but **all changes to persistent database state within the block are
> rolled back**.

Bold emphasis mine. Related:

- [PostgreSQL cannot begin/end transactions in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550241/postgresql-cannot-begin-end-transactions-in-pl-pgsql/14550315#14550315)

To actually `COMMIT` work  at any point in the process, you need a [`PROCEDURE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html), introduced with Postgres 11. Starting with the same version, transaction control statements are also allowed in anonymous code blocks executed with the [`DO` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html).

Basically:

```sql
DO
$do$
DECLARE
  _rec "UsagePs";
BEGIN
   FOR _rec IN
      SELECT * FROM "UsagePs" u WHERE u.foo = 'bar' ORDER BY u.id
   LOOP
      BEGIN 
         PERFORM public.process_single_usage(_rec);
         -- COMMIT; -- ? -- requires Postgres 11
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
            RAISE WARNING 'This error happened: %!', SQLERRM;
      END;
   END LOOP;
END
$do$;
```

I don't think you even need or want to `COMMIT` inside the loop. You just want to roll back subtransactions - or everything.

Note the use of `SQLERRM` to propagate any error message from the child function out, downgraded to `WARNING`. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-EXCEPTION-DIAGNOSTICS)

> The special variable `SQLERRM` contains the error message associated with the exception.

Related:

- [Can I use EXCEPTIONs in a FOR LOOP to force continuation on error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325687/can-i-use-exceptions-in-a-for-loop-to-force-continuation-on-error/20341424#20341424)
- [PostgreSQL INSERT or UPDATE values given a SELECT result after a trigger has been hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27629134/postgresql-insert-or-update-values-given-a-select-result-after-a-trigger-has-bee/27630409#27630409)